# Cannot insert data into my feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I'm using Arcgis 10.1 and I created my script for inserting data in my feature class but I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SIG_AS\Shapefiles\Projet2\MyScript\Insert_chantiers_gp.py", line 35, in <module>
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor( inGeodatabase, fieldsToUpdate) as cursor:
RuntimeError: cannot open 'Chantiers.shp'
```

And this is my script for inserting my data into my feature class:

```
# Ajout de champs
import arcgisscripting
import arcpy
# Définir l'environnement
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/SIG_AS/DB/Chantiers.gdb"

# creation de l'objet gp (arcgisscripting est l'ancêtre d'arcpy et devait être créé à chaque fois)
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3) 
# Paramètres d'entrée
inDescription = gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
inRestriction = gp.GetParameterAsText(1)
inNumero = gp.GetParameterAsText(2)
inNomVoie = gp.GetParameterAsText(3)
inDate1 = gp.GetParameterAsText(4)
inDate2 = gp.GetParameterAsText(5)
inLat = gp.GetParameterAsText(6)
inLong = gp.GetParameterAsText(7)

# Variables de champs
inGeodatabase = "Chantiers.shp"
ObjectidField = "OBJECTID"
ShapeField = "SHAPE"
descriptionField = "Desc_travaux"
restrictionField = "Restriction_trafic"
numeroField = "Numero_civique"
nomField = "Nom_voie"
date1Field = "Date_debut"
date2Field = "Date_fin"
LatField = "Latitude"
LongField = "Longitude"

#Tuple pour mise à jour des champs
fieldsToUpdate = ( ObjectidField, ShapeField, descriptionField, restrictionField, numeroField, nomField, date1Field, date2Field, LatField, LongField)
# Curseur d'insertion
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor( inGeodatabase, fieldsToUpdate) as cursor:
# Insertion de ligne aux attributs considérés
    cursor.insertRow((inDescription, inRestriction, inNumero, inNomVoie, inDate1, inDate2, inLat, inLong))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be trying to open C:/SIG_AS/DB/Chantiers.**gdb**/Chantiers.**shp**, but feature classes in geodatabases are not shapefiles. If the feature class is in fact in that geodatabase and is called "Chantiers", try `inGeodatabase = "Chantiers"`. Otherwise, change `arcpy.env.workspace` to the *folder* containing Chantiers.shp.

Answer (score 2):

Your workspace is a geodatabase (C:/SIG_AS/DB/Chantiers.gdb); however, you're trying to open Chantiers.shp. Shapefiles cannot exist in a geodatabase. Either Chantiers is a feature class within the gdb, and you meant to pass only Chantiers (without the .shp) to the variable inGeodatabase (which is a terribly misleading variable name, by the way), or you have a shapefile named Chantiers elsewhere that you're trying to reference. In that case, assign the full path of Chantiers.shp to the variable.